# DynamicResource wont change color

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, maui

First of all I created two themes inside resources directory
[image]

Then I added light theme and changed some dynamic resources to SecondaryColor which is black

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8" ?>
<Application xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Eden"
             x:Class="Eden.App">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Themes/LightTheme.xaml"/>

            <Style TargetType="Label">
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{DynamicResource SecondaryColor}" />
                <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="OpenSansRegular" />
            </Style>

            <Style TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{DynamicResource SecondaryColor}" />
                <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="OpenSansRegular" />
                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{DynamicResource SecondaryColor}" />
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="14,10" />
            </Style>

        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Light Theme

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                    x:Class="Eden.Resources.Themes.LightTheme">
    <Color x:Key="PageBackgroundColor">White</Color>
    <Color x:Key="NavigationBarColor">WhiteSmoke</Color>
    <Color x:Key="PrimaryColor">WhiteSmoke</Color>
    <Color x:Key="SecondaryColor">Black</Color>
    <Color x:Key="PrimaryTextColor">Black</Color>
    <Color x:Key="SecondaryTextColor">White</Color>
    <Color x:Key="TertiaryTextColor">Gray</Color>
    <Color x:Key="TransparentColor">Transparent</Color>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

But when I open app button background is white.
[image]

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you try "Background" instead of "BackgroundColor"? Also TextColor and BackgroundColor should be diffrent

Comment: This is official demo. It works with colors like "black" "red".. it only wont work with my themes.

Comment: Can you try giving hex value to Secondary color i.e #000000. The Background is of Brush type so might be the case it is not converting it to SolidColorBrush which is default.

Comment: @Soft_API_Dev no change

Comment: Had you tried to check the other properties is right? You can try to set the text color as blue to check the resource is used or not. This can make you now the problem is the `Background` or the `<ResourceDictionary>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a test app and it works here.

This is different ,there are xaml.cs files

[image]

Added a DarkTheme.xaml   ( `ContentPage` )

[image]

And change it to `ResourceDictionary`
[image]

This is how it looks in your example code

[image]

LightTheme.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="MauiApp1.LightTheme">
<Color x:Key="PageBackgroundColor">White</Color>
<Color x:Key="NavigationBarColor">WhiteSmoke</Color>
<Color x:Key="PrimaryColor">WhiteSmoke</Color>
<Color x:Key="SecondaryColor">Black</Color>
<Color x:Key="PrimaryTextColor">Black</Color>
<Color x:Key="SecondaryTextColor">White</Color>
<Color x:Key="TertiaryTextColor">Gray</Color>
<Color x:Key="TransparentColor">Transparent</Color>
```

App.xaml.cs

```
 <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>

 <!--If you want to use LightTheme and DarkTheme add both--> 
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Themes/LightTheme.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Themes/DarkTheme.xaml"/>
            <Style TargetType="Label">
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{DynamicResource SecondaryColor}" />
                <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="OpenSansRegular" />
            </Style>

        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{DynamicResource SecondaryColor}" />
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="OpenSansRegular" />
            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{DynamicResource SecondaryColor}" />
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="14,10" />
        </Style>



    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Your example code is here https://github.com/borisoprit/MauiApp1

Comment: There can be the problem. Thank you very much looks great :)